How to read an directory extension from an application object in Entra ID?
I want to read the below directory extension from an application object (say, App1) in Entra ID.
It's shown in the application object's manifest (see below) and its definition is returned by the Get-MgApplicationExtensionProperty -ApplicationId App2 cmdlet for another application object (say, App2).
However, when retrieving the application object using Get-MgApplication -ApplicationId App1, I don't see any properties to read its value.
How can I read the directory extension (not its definition)?


Its a relationship https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships, with a direct call Invoke-MgGraphRequest 'v1.0/applications/{applicationObjectId}?$expand=extensionProperties with the cmdlet Get-MgApplication ... -Expand extensionProperties might work

@SantiagoSquarzon Thank you, but you're not right. I'm not looking for directory extension definitions, but directory extension attributes (name/value pairs) on target objects e.g. {User, Group, AdministrativeUnit, Application}

In this case, the extension attribute definitions has been applied on an application, but I can't retrieve its value, despite seeing it in the application manifest

If you have a directory extension that can be added to an application then you can get the directory extension attributes by specifying the extension in $select
For a specific app
GET /v1.0/applications/{app_id}?$select=id,displayName,extension_7bb6cee95f7746b294a57cb3a_somename

PowerShell SDK
Get-MgApplication -ApplicationId App1 -Property "id,displayName,extension_7bb6cee95f7746b294a57cb3a_somename"

For all apps
GET /v1.0/applications?$select=id,displayName,extension_7bb6cee95f7746b294a57cb3a_somename

PowerShell SDK
Get-MgApplication -Property "id,displayName,extension_7bb6cee95f7746b294a57cb3a_somename" 


Thank you. Can I only get it by using $select? What if I want all properties of the application in addition to the extension attribute. Do I then need to specify all those properties using -Property (PowerShell)? I assume, -Property uses $select under the covers?

@Shuzheng The extension attributes are returned only on $select. Once you use $select, you need to specify all properties to be returned manually.  -Property uses $select under the covers.

Is there a way to say "return all extension attributes" without knowing their names in advance?

You need to know the attributes names and specify them in $select. You should be able to use Get-MgApplication -ExpandProperty "extensionProperties"  to get all applications and their extension attributes definitions. On client, you can filter those extensions that can be applied to applications. Select their names, concatenate them and use in Get-MgApplication -Property "id,displayName,extension_a,extension_b,..."

FYI, the directory extension attributes are returned in AdditionalProperties, which took some time to figure out
